# Returning a New Instance of Vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, return, new-operator

I have tried to examine [The C++ Classes Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/), however, I was unable to find an answer to the following. Consider a simple implementation of Merge Sort using iterators as arguments:

```
std::vector<int> mergesort(std::vector<int>::iterator begin, std::vector<int>::iterator end)
{
    if (end - begin <= 1)
    {
        std::vector<int> c(begin, end);
        return c;
    }
    int mid = (end - begin) / 2;

    std::vector<int> a = mergesort(begin, begin + mid);
    std::vector<int> b = mergesort(begin + mid, end);

    return merge(a, b);
}
```

At the base case of the recursion, where i write `std::vector<int> c(begin, end)` and then return the vector, I would like to instead write `return std::vector<int>::vector(begin, end)`, that is, to create and return the vector in one line rather than being forced to localize it first.

How would I go about this, since I cannot use the constructor directly as suggested?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call its constructor like so:

```
return std::vector<int>(begin, end);
```

Comment: Perfect, I did not realize that was the correct syntax. Thanks! NB: Will be marked as answer after time limit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
return std::vector<int>(begin, end);
```